# Library resources not accessible from cordova Android application

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, plugins

I have added external android project as a library in cordova android project from eclipse still Resources of library project is not accessible.

Library reference is also got added in project.properties (android.library.reference.2 = ...)

Getting the following error in the log:

> 01-15 12:20:52.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1132): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: .R$layout

Let me know the exact process to add external android library in Cordova android project.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution.
If you want to access any resources from plugin source files then instead of using R.id.xxx or R.layout.xxx use FakeR.java file which you will get on the net.
FakeR will get resources from the current project R.java instead of plugin's R.java